# Auto-insertion of quotes fail when a closing bracket is on the same line

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I have gone to Tools > Preferences > Editor > Advanced Settings and checked the following:

- Automatic insertion of parentheses, braces and brackets
- Automatic insertion of closing quotes

I was expecting that when I type `print("`, auto insert would have completed both the quotes and bracket for me.

Instead, when I type `print(`, auto insert has inserted the closing bracket automatically and I get `print()`.

Then I type one quotation mark `"`, auto insert fails to close the quote and I get `print(")`.

If I were to type a line break between the parentheses like so

`print(
)`

Then when I type one quotation mark `"`, auto insert works again to give me:

`print(""
)`

It's not game-breaking but it is annoying for sure. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We'll fix this in Spyder 4, to be released in 2019. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/6827) was opened on Github on 23rd March 2018, and was fixed in [this PR](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/8659) on 29th January 2019. The issue can be solved by upgrading Spyder to the latest version.